# How acces to audio library in SWIFT 3

Tags: swift3

I would just like to allow the user to import the sound he wants into the application. Please help me I haven't found any tutorials. and I'm a beginner in swift.

Answer (score 0):

Use MPMediaLibrary ....
let library = MPMediaLibrary()